# Why HttpClient.PostAsyc().Result can be used in a sync method?

Tags: c#, async-await

as far as I know, calling the `Result` property of a `Task` returned by an `async` method would cause deadlock in a Winform application. For example, the code below can cause deadlock:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var r = MyAsyncFunc().Result;
}
```

But calling `HttpClient.PostAsync().Result` seems have no problem. What is the magic?

Answer (score 0):

In most scenarios, the UI thread is single threaded. Anything called from or going to the UI thread should be invoked. So,

var myResult = Http.Client.PostAsync().Result; //is fine, but

TextBox_t.Text = Http.Client.PostAsync().Result; //is not so good.

You'd have to Invoke back to the UI thread any results from an async operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one thread in a winforms application which is allowed to update the UI, you can't update the UI from a background thread and you can't await a background thread without locking up the UI.

Below is a stripped down example of somewhere I've use a background process to download a file and update a progress bar using Background Workers. I was using WebClient.

```
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    //setup delegate for download progress changed. - runs in bw thread
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something here every time the background worker is updated e.g. update download progress percentage ready to update progress bar in UI.
        double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
        int progress = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
        bw.ReportProgress(progress);
    });

   //setup delegate for download backgroub worker progress changed. - runs in UI thread
    bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(delegate(object o, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this thread has access to UI, e.g. take variable from above and set it in UI.
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    });

    //setup delegate for download completion. - runs in bw thread
    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something here when download finishes
    });

    //setup delegate for backgroud worker finished. - runs in UI thread
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something here than needs to update the UI.
    });

    //MAIN CODE BLOCK for backgroud worker
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        // execute the main code here than needs to run in background. e.g. start download.
        // this is where you would start the download in webClient. e.g. webClient.DownloadString("some url here");
    });

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```